# How to get the web page to redirect?

Tags: javascript, html

The thing is that is not working is that the page does not redirect to another page, weather if it is wrong or right.  I want the page to redirect to another page if the user guesses the generated word right.

Comment: Please provide some code example of what you already tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just need to preventDefault the form submission,
use this code to prevent it

```
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
  })
```

Comment: What if the answer is wrong, I am getting right even though I wrote the wrong answer???

Comment: preventing the form from its default behavior has nothing to do with your logic,

Answer (score 0):

```
function myFunction() {
    if (document.getElementById("Enter_the_word").value == "KEYBOARD") {
        location.href = 'index4.html';
    } else {
      location.href = "index.html";
    }

  }
```

Your code has no issues but please try this reversed condition. If it helps you.

MY EDITED CODE BELOW -----------------

```
var answerArr = ['KEYBOARD','MATH','FOOTBALL'];
if(answerArr.includes('MATH')){
    location.href = 'index4.html';
}else{
    location.href = 'index4.html';
}
```

Like this

Comment: I want to use multiple words and not only keyboard, So if the user writes KEYBOARD,MATH AND FOOTBALL, it should go to index.html

Comment: Here in that case, You can store your answer keywords in array and check if the given answer is in array or not. This will work dynamically for you. you just need to maintain array of answers